# How can i skip a second iteration if the first iteration (for) is true? [java]

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to write a code that print the range between 2 numbers, from the smallest to the biggest.
for example: 
let say i enter two numbers - 3 and 6 
i need it to print it like that: 3 4 5 6
now my problem is if i enter the two numbers like 6 and 3 
than i have a problem with the first iteration because when i enter 3 and 6 it finish the loop and go to the next one... and i don't want that, i want him to end the program if the first iteration is true.

the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForClass
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two numbers");
        int num1, num2;
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        num2 = scan.nextInt();

        for(;num1<=num2;num1++){
                System.out.print(num1);  

            }

        for(;num2<=num1;num2++){  
                    System.out.print(num2);                
        }
    }
}
```

Tests:
3 and 6 
go to the first for loop, run it and then go to the second for
then print 
3 4 5 6 6 7
and that's wrong  i want it to print 
3 4 5 6
and end the program.

***i should point out that i must use the for-loop.

Comment: `return` will stop execution of current function.

Comment: An iteration is one time through a loop. It isn't true or false. What is it you are really asking?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a boolean and only execute the second for loop if it's true...

```
boolean executed = false;

for ( /* code here */ ) {
    executed = true;
    /* code here */
}

if (!executed) {
    for ( /* code here */ ) {
        /* code here */
    }    
}
```

However, in your case a better approach would be to work out which of the numbers is smaller:

```
int smaller, bigger;
if (num1 > num2) {
    smaller = num2;
    bigger = num1;
} else { /* may want to do something different if they are equal */
    bigger = num2;
    smaller = num1;
}
```

Then you only need a single loop, and you just need to use `bigger` and `smaller` with it.

Comment: `smaller = Math.min(num1, num2); bigger = Math.max(num1, num2);`

Comment: Absolutely a better way to do the snippet above; I just wanted to keep it as basic as possible.

Comment: And there is no harm in doing that. Especially by showing the purpose of `if/else` blocks :).

Answer (score 1):

Your for loops are BOTH executing.  They are both working too.  Your results are `3,4,5,6` (now num1 = 7, which is not <= 6) and `6,7` so an if statement to select the correct loop should solve your problems.  Something like

```
if (num1 < num2) { 
  //loop 1 
} 
else //loop 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;
With one for loop;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter two numbers");
        int num1, num2;
        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        num2 = scan.nextInt();
        int start, end;
        if (num1 > num2) {
            start = num2;
            end = num1;
        } else {
            start = num1;
            end = num2;
        }
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your first for loop put this code.

```
if(num2 < num1){
    int temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
}
```

Then erase your second for loop. This way of exchanging two variables with only one temporary variable is useful to learn.

Answer (score -1):

Any time you want you break a loop, `break;` will help you!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if(i == 10) break;
}
```

That'll break the loop once i hits 10.

Comment: I usually feel that one should note/comment that it breaks code flow though